# Add attribute with JSON value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, escaping

I want to add and store json in a `data-` attribute via jQuery.
Problem is: when I add the attribute containing the json and escaped double quotes, it's added with the exact `&quot;` and not the escaped double quotes.

Output:

```
<div data-myjson="{&quot;number&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}"></div>
```

Expected: Browser should treat `&quot;` as double quotes and not as plain characters

```
<div data-myjson="{"number":"1"}"></div>  // with escaped inner quotes
```

My jquery

```
$("div").attr("data-myjson", "{&quot;number&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}");
```

How can add actually escaped double quotes in the HTML itself?

Comment: `attr()` takes a raw value, not escaped HTML.

Comment: I'm assuming the browser take &quot; and convert them. I know jQuery won't do that.

Comment: Why does your string contain &quot; in the first place? I would assume it would be a Javascript object as fedeghe defined it in his answer below.

Comment: The json being added is just a plain string that will be retrieved and used later as a json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, if the text containing  the `&quot;` is a plain string as described above, the how about decoding it using:

```
var str = '{&quot;number&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}';
$("div").attr("data-myjson", $('<div/>').html(str).text());
```

Comment: But would the double quotes be escape properly with this method?

Comment: I believe so. Try it: https://jsfiddle.net/ofadazjn/. Is this the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

what about using JSON.stringify (and JSON.parse to extract) ?

```
var o = {"number":"1"};
$("div").attr("data-myjson", JSON.stringify(o));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `attr` takes a string value (as opposed to "HTML"), simply use single quotes (`'`) and then pass in the *actual* [JSON] value:

```
$("div").attr("data-myjson", '{"number":"1"}');
```

HTML entities, including `&quote;`, are not processed in CDATA sections, such as the content of `<script>` tags.

Terminology nit: `attr` updates the [HTML] DOM which is the tree graph representing the document, but not the HTML source/text from which the DOM was initially parsed. Only a few functions like `html` consider data "as" HTML.

Comment: I know this solution but I was thinking the double quotes would need to be escaped